# Passing python dictionary into matlab

Tags: matlab, python-3.5

I need to pass python dictionary into matlab and matlab returns the variable after performing some operation as follows:

Matlab function in file named `useMatlab4Sum.m`:

```
function matlabSum = useMatlab4Sum(var)
    varin = struct(var)
    a = varin.var
    arr = varin.arr
    return a*arr(:)
```

In Python:

```
myDict = {'a':2, 'arr':np.array([[1, 2],[3, 4]])}
eng = matlab.engine.start_matlab()
params = eng.useMatlab4Sum(myDict)
eng.quit
```

But I get the error:

```
TypeError: unsupported Python data type: numpy.ndarray
```

I have a more complicated case that I am working through, I am just using the above simple case for example.

Comment: It seems is is not the dictionary but the numpy.ndarray that is problematic. Maybe this commend and the ones around it can help you: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/157347-convert-python-numpy-array-to-double#comment_283741

Comment: Have you tried the workarounds which are discussed in the link Cris Luengo shared?

Answer (score 0):

This problem is due to the diffrent handling of data type in python and matlab.
you must change your code into this :

```
useMatlab4Sum(py.array.array(var))
```

more information on [this link](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/handling-data-returned-from-python.html):

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass the 'arr' as a list. use `(arr.flatten()).tolist()`, then in Matlab do this [ClickHere](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/216498-passing-numpy-ndarray-from-python-to-matlab#comment_284973)